# Create Table by Copying Structure of Existing Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, create-table

I am trying to create a new table by copying an existing table in SQL Server 2008 using Management Studio. The existing table contains no data. I am using the following code but am receiving an error for Incorrect Syntax near AS. I am not sure what is wrong here. I am a SQL newb and any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

```
CREATE TABLE Drop_Centers_Detail
    AS (Select * From Centers_Detail)
```

Comment: Problem also applies to MS Access using ODBC (and the accepted answer resolves the problem too)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

like this, however this will not create indexes and constraints

```
select * into Drop_Centers_Detail
from Centers_Detail
where 1 = 0
```

Comment: Supporting documentation - INTO clause: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx

Comment: be sure to read the "Limitations and Restrictions" in the link given by @OMG Ponies.  You won't get computed columns, indexes, constraints, or triggers from the source table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the info. It worked. Just out of curiosity is there a way to copy an existing table and preserve its indexes, constraints, etc.?

Comment: you will need to script it out in that case or you can use SMO (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx)

Comment: Great answer! The problem and solution also apply to MS Access using ODBC and the Microsoft JET drivers. Several sources claim the syntax to be that given by the OP, so its a bit confusing...

Answer (score 3):

In Sql Server Managment Studio, right-click your existing table and select `Script Table as > Create to > New Query Editor Window`. This will give you a better starting script that you can use as the base for your new schema.

Answer (score 0):

1) I would suggest generating a create script from the table you want to copy, and then run that on your destination database.

2) Write a Insert statement in another SQL Query window to import that data

Insert Into Database1.Table1(Field1, Field2)
Select Field1, Field2 From Database2.Table