# Create SQL table as copy of an existing table (ODBC and C#)

Tags: c#, ms-access, odbc

Using ODBC to manipulate an Access database in C#.

All of the following do NOT create the table. Each generates the exception `Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement.`:

```
sqlQuery = "CREATE TABLE SpecialScans AS (SELECT * FROM Scans);"
sqlQuery = "CREATE TABLE [SpecialScans] AS (SELECT * FROM [Scans]);"
sqlQuery = "CREATE TABLE [SpecialScans] AS SELECT * FROM [Scans];"
// And all of the above with " WHERE 1=2;" to create just the schema
```

This follows the syntax specified [on the w3schools website](https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_create_table.asp) and elsewhere.

But the syntax given in the accepted answer [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868102) works fine:

```
sqlQuery = "SELECT * INTO [SpecialScans] FROM [Scans];"
// And with " WHERE 1=2;" to create just the schema
```

Why does the former fail but the latter work?

Comment: access isnt a real database is the best answer i can give

Comment: Seems to be related to the MS-Access SQL dialect.

Comment: @Ctznkane525 That's not the point, because it doesn't work in SQL Server either. The point is: every RDBMS is different, use the correct dialect for yours.

Comment: The w3schools site (and several others) show the former syntax to be correct. I've found no site that showed the working syntax so "following it" is a bit of a challenge! :o)

Comment: The fact that you're trying to create a table with the same structure as another table indicates a database design flaw. Better to add the "special" scans to the regular scans table and add just the id to special scans table. Alternatively, add a "special" flag to the scans table.

Comment: CREATE TABLE SELECT is supposed to be MySQL and Oracle valid.

Comment: I have found that "SELECT from MyTable INTO newTable FROM MyTable" works for most databases - can't say CREATE table from select is all that common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out, be it Oracle, MySQL, SQL server, FoxPro etc. etc. etc.?

The commands tend to differ by QUITE LARGE of a margin.

While for a simple SELECT statement, and even quite much most SQL joins, most databases that support SQL are quite simular for things like SELECT's.

However, when it comes to creating tables - then databases REALLY start to show their differances. Some have specific types of columns, many have different types of indexes - the list is VERY long.

While JET/ACE (the MS-Access database does claim ansi-92 compatiblity, the standards don't define say WHEN you want to copy a table for example - that a big rabbit hole - each vendor has differing means.

However, the JET/ACE Access syntax for what we call a make table query?

This code will work:

```
public void Test()
{
// make table query
string strSQL = "SELECT tblHotels.* INTO tblHotelsCopy FROM tblHotels";

using (OdbcCommand cmdSQL = new OdbcCommand(strSQL, new OdbcConnection(My.Settings.TestAccessDB)))
{
    cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
    cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
}
```

So in above, we using SELECT -> INTO. (and that syntax actually works on SQL server also).

so that sql as per above, works with SQL server, also works with MS-Access.

In above we are sending the table to a NEW TABLE. Hence this is what we would call a make table.

There is also the ability to "append" data from one table to the other table. This would thus allow you to send/transfer data from one table to another (existing) table.

This works in Access SQL but NOT sql server!!!

```
INSERT INTO tblHotelsCopy SELECT * FROM tblHotels
```

In sql server, you in general HAVE to specify all the columns - but in Access SQL you don't! - so this is a example of how Access SQL is somewhat more flexible.

So above is now NOT a MAKE-table, since the target table MUST exist. So, in above we inserting rows from tblHotels to tblhotelsCopy - they will be appended.

So, you want to VERY careful keep in mind

```
 MAKE table query - that creates the new target table

 APPEND table query - that sends a select of rows from one table into EXISTING table.
```

Comment: Well, if you include a PK value or autonumber, or that each table is not the same, then you get errors. Try building the query in access - use query builder, and from ribbon change to a append query. As noted, that would be an append query. Start a new question - show the code and the sql you are using. BOTH of the syntaxes I outlined in this question are tested, and do work. The code example uses the ODBC provider, and both oleDB or the odbc provider should work. So, start a new question. post the actual code you are using, the sql you are using. and the structure of the two tables.

Comment: After you use the access query builder - flip to sql view, and look close at the syntax. Regardless, start a new question. Post your code, post the sql, and post the two table structures . Your question is to create a copy of a table, and yet you now trying a insert into - which is a append query and thus the target table is assumed to exist. i mean, no surprise that this question was closed. Which do you want, a a append query (move data to existing table, or a make table query - move data to a new non existing table. As I stated, without a code sample? This is become a waste of time here.

Comment: yes, you actually have to read the answer i gave here. Without reading what I posted, you not going to get anything working. As I stated, start a new question. Post the code you are using. And also post the table structure.